# Typescript: make mappings from custom types?

Tags: typescript

I am new to Typescript, but have been reading the docs (in relation to this question, specifically this [page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)).

To help solidify my understanding of typescript I am starting small, by typing an "API". Suppose this one of this API's request parameters is `format`. The developer might get the `String` literal of this format but the API expects an `Integer`.  In this instance on of the request parameters appears to be an `enum` (although in the general case it might be a `String` to `String` mapping, or something else):

```
// this case can be done via enum
enum Format = {JSON = 1, CSV = 2, XML = 3}
```

This of course is fine for finite, known, and preferably *small* amounts of options.  My question, is how should one, in typescript, generalize the following :

```
// code might use helper types ?
type FormatName = 'JSON' | 'CSV' | 'XML'
type FormatIndex = 1|2|3

// code might use "maps" for quick convert / validation
const mapFormatNameToIndex = {
  JSON: 1,
  CSV:  2,
  XML:  3
}

const mapFormatIndexToName = {
  1: 'JSON',
  2: 'CSV',
  3: 'XML'
}

// might validate for error handling via something like this
const isValidFormatName = (maybeIsFormatName: String | FormatName): Boolean | null => {
  const validFormatNames = Set(Object.keys(mapFormatNameToIndex))
  return validFormatNames.has(maybeIsFormatName)
}
```

Ideally `mapFormatNameToIndex` and `mapFormatIndexToName` can be automatically generated from the types?

```
// this is pseudocode for what I would like
const mapFormatNameToIndex = {
  [key: FormatName]: FormatIndex
}
const mapFormatIndexToName = {
  [key: FormatIndex]: FormatName
}

// assumes that the hand defined options for the types are enumerable
for (let i = 0; i < FormatName.length; ) {
  mapped[FormatIndex[i]] = FormatName[i]]
}
```

Please feel free to point me to other reading resources / better syntax / conventions than that above.

e.g. perhaps type guards are more appropriate?

```
function isFormatName(maybeIsFormatName: String | FormatName): maybeIsFormatName is FormatName {
    // idk if this works
    return (<FormatName>maybeIsFormatName);
}
```

Comment: I don't think I'm really clear about what you're asking; the `enum` mostly acts like the mappings you're asking for, so I don't see why you're trying to emulate it.  I don't understand why an `enum` only works for a small number of options... or rather, I do understand it, but I don't understand why the other code would work any better... somewhere you need to list out all the options. Could you include some code examples for why you can't just use the original `enum`?

Comment: Also, you don't want to use `String` (an instance of something created with the `String` constructor); you probably mean just `string` (the primitive string type).  And `string | FormatName` would just be `string`.